# How to convert characters to something like '\x{ff41}' in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I see some data format like `\x{ff41}` in my regex patterns. I know how to use it via some examples but  don't know what it  means in PHP.And now I need to figure out whether a character is included by a sequence with range like `\x{FF10}-\x{FF19}` .Help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are Unicode-Characters (you're probably using the /u parameter). If you want to look up which symbol your "code" stands for, you can use http://unicode.org/charts/ (there is an input-field on the top).

You'll find the information you need on this particular example in
http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFF00.pdf

Answer (score 0):

i hope the URl will show you a better way.

```
http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php
http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html
```